# What does this error mean that I get when trying to start an emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

I am using `Eclipse 4.4(Luna)` and am trying to start an Emulator to test my android application and I am getting the following error:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'droidX'
WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\world_000\.android\avd\droidX.avd/sdcard.img
WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: Open HAX device failed
creating window 0 0 238 423
```

The emulator opens on a black screen with `android` written across the middle, I then try to run my application as an `android application` and get the following messages:

```
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] Performing com.example.james.zafar.FullscreenActivity activity launch
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'droidX'
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] Uploading FirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] Failed to install FirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory
[2014-08-09 10:34:17 - FirstApp] Launch canceled!
```

Can someone explain why I am getting these errors and how I can go about fixing them please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\world_000\.android\avd\droidX.avd/sdcard.img
```

means you are trying to open emulator which you have already opened.Close that & then try to open.